# jQuery rating - how to show chosen value on hover?

Tags: jquery, live, rate

I'm using `jquery.rating.js` plugin and I wrote a litle function that shows the value of clicked input but I want to show the value on hover too.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('.star-rating-on')) {
    $('.star-rating-on a').live('click', function() {
        var note1 = $('.star-rating-on a:last').attr('title');
        $('#i-choose').html(note1 +'.0');
    });
} else { 
    $('.star-rating-hover a:last').live('hover', function() {
        var note = $('.star-rating-hover a:last').attr('title');
        $('#i-choose').html(note +'.0');
    });
} 
})
```

the html

```
<input type="radio" class="star required" value="1" name="rating" />
<input type="radio" class="star required" value="2" name="rating" />
<input type="radio" class="star required" value="3" name="rating" />
<input type="radio" class="star required" value="4" name="rating" />
<input type="radio" class="star required" value="5" name="rating" />
<div id="i-choose">Your rate</div>
```

first problem: on hover doesn't show the value.
second problem: show earlier selected value if I accidentaly point cursor on the input.

Comment: I am confused by your question. Most likely due to the fact your grammar starts so well and then just tails off to complete nonsense. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: live is being deprecated in favor of http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: im not working on jQ 1.7.1 so .on() is not allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to involve jQuery in the hover feature, unless I've misunderstood something or unless you want to style the hover text.

If you add `title="1"` to the input then the tooltip will display `1` when you hover it.

Comment: Nice! You should accept this answer if it helped you. Otherwise write what you did in an own answer and accept that =)